# custom role provider for user.isuserinrole mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor

I have a c# mvc razor web application with custom membership and everything works wonderful.
I am able to get the logged in user name by using this: `user.identity.name`.
I have a database of usernames and their roles.
Now the problem is, in one of my views I am trying to restrict access to only "admin"
so i tried using `user.isinrole` however, this always returned false.
so then i tried using `roles.isuserinrole`, then i get an exception that says its not enabled.

i Google around and found several custom controllers for role provider that has the function `isuserinrole`.

my question is, do i need to create a custom contoller for `isuserinrole` to be enabled?
in my view when i enter `roles.` --> visual studio list a list of built in functions that has `isuserinrole`, so my question is, will creating my own custom role provider override the built in functions?

assuming i have the custom function, how will my web application tie it all in and check if user is in role?

thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a custom role provider. [This page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) goes into the basics.

The custom role provider should inherit from the abstract class `System.Web.Security.RoleProvider`. In this class, you can then implement the abstract method `IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)` to provide the logic that you need to answer the `IsUserInRole` call properly based on your application needs.

Comment: that's exactly what I figured!

Answer (score 0):

You may add `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` attribute to your Action or to Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the interface, with something like this

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(MVVMLogin LoginData)
    {
      //validate user against database
      var IsValid = true;

        if (IsValid == true)
        {

                var Roles = "admin";

                var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                    1,
                    LoginData.Username,
                    DateTime.Now,
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), //Expires
                    false,
                    Roles,
                    "/");

                var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        }

        return View();
    }
```

and in the global.asax you can add the following

```
  protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User == null) return;
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return;
        if (!(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)) return;

        var id = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
        var ticket = id.Ticket;
        var userData = ticket.UserData;
        var roles = userData.Split(new[] { ',' });

        HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
    }
```

now you can control which type of users can access the controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin,user")]
public class CampaignsController : Controller
```